# Change content of HTML page from another page

Tags: html

I am programming a while and i have a question. Can I make a HTML page change things & settings that  affect the other HTML page? Like a user interface? Does it need PHP? Of course all these need to be uploaded on the internet!

Is it possible?

Comment: If they're separate pages, there's no direct way. I suppose you could send the data about changes back to server and have the other page continuosly poll your server to see if any changes have been made.

Comment: Is it possible to write a web application which accepts user input?  Yes, yes it is.  (Hint: We're using one right now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Can I make a HTML page change things & settings that affect the other HTML page?**

  Yes, you can.
- **Like a user interface?**

  Sure, why not?
- **Does it need PHP?**

  I wouldn't say it *needs* PHP, but it is one way, possibly. There are many ways to do that.
- **Is it possible?**

  Totally!

Anyway, I'm answering your question, even being of low quality, risking to be downvoted, to say that it's possible to do what you want. But you have to actually search and try something. Then, if you get stuck at any point, you can post a more specific question here on SO, and we will be glad to help!!

Comment: For example changing the text and images?

Comment: Perhaps, you are looking for a technology called CMS - Content Managment System... Take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. You can write your settings to a configuration file and then use this file to affect the content on other pages. Frameworks like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (Python) and [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/) (PHP) and cool CMSs like [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) (PHP) have mechanisms that let you do this so you don't have to re-invent the wheel.